# Java regex for replacing exact match

Tags: java, regex

My java app is trying to modify the following line from a file:

```
static int a = 5;
```

The goal is to replace 'a' with 'mod_a'.

Using a simple `string.replace(var_name, "mod" + var_name)` gives me the following:

```
stmod_atic int mod_a = 5;
```

Which is quite simply wrong. Googling around i found that you can prepend "\b" and then var_name has to represent the beginning of a word, however, `string.replace("\\b" + var_name, "mod" + var_name)` does absolutely nothing :(

(I also tested with "\b" instead of "\b")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `\b` here is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) meaning a word boundary, so it's pretty much what you want.
- [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) does **not** use regular expressions (so `\b` will match only the literal `\b`).
- [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) *does* use regular expressions
- You can also use `\b` *both* before *and* after your variable, to avoid replacing "aDifferentVariable" with "mod_aDifferentVariable".

So the a possible solution would be this:

```
String result = "static int a = 5;".replaceAll("\\ba\\b", "mod_a");
```

or more general:

```
static String prependToWord(String input, String word, String prefix) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b", Matcher.quoteReplacement(prefix + word));
}
```

Note that I use `Pattern.qoute()` in case `word` contains any characters that have a meaning in regular expressions. For a similar reason [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) is used on the replacement String.

Comment: I'd love to give you another vote for the Pattern.quote suggestion, alas I can't :(

Comment: Bear in mind that regular expressions are not perfect in matching complex semantics like programming languages. For instance trying to replace `a` with `mod_a` @Joachim's regex will also affect comments and other instances of that identifier. Example: `class a { public a(int a) {...` will become `class a_mod { public a_mod(int a_mod) {...`. Oops.

Comment: @LisMorski: very true: regular expressions are no replacement for true refactoring tools! But in a pinch they are might useful, provided you visually scan the result for sanity ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
string.replaceAll("\\b" + var_name + "\\b", "mod" + var_name);
```

Comment: It works. However I'm going to accept Sauer's answer because of more detailed explination. Don't fret however, one vote for the runner-up!

Comment: Haha, no worries! He was first too.